# Elixir exrm console works but application does not start automatically

Tags: elixir, exrm

I [asked a question previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721605/elixir-exrm-release-crashes-on-eredis-start-link) about getting [exrm](https://github.com/bitwalker/exrm) working for my project. The answer got me to the point that I can build my release (in dev mode) and access it via the console.

However there are a couple problems:

1. When I open the console via `rel/my_app/bin/my_app console`, my application **does not actually start**. I have to call `Application.start(:my_app)` to get it going.
2. Calling `rel/my_app/bin/my_app start` does not start my app. I can see that the epmd, beam.smp, and run_erl processes have started, but my own application does not appear to be running.

Pretty sure these two problems are related.

**Steps taken for console:**

```
$ mix release --dev
$ ./rel/my_app/bin/my_app console
iex(my_app@127.0.0.1)1> Application.start(:my_app)
# at this point the app is running until I ctrl+c
```

**Steps taken for start:**

```
$ mix release --dev
$ ./rel/my_app/bin/my_app start

$ ps aux | grep "my_app"

12235   0.0  0.0  2460212    636   ??  S    11:10am   0:00.19 /Users/me/code/my_app/rel/my_app/erts-6.3.1/bin/epmd -daemon

17565   0.0  0.2  2524256  26236 s008  Ss+   4:03pm   0:00.37 /Users/me/code/my_app/rel/my_app/erts-6.3.1/bin/beam.smp -- -root /Users/me/code/my_app/rel/my_app -progname Users/me/code/my_app/rel/my_app/bin/my_app -- -home /Users/me -- -boot /Users/me/code/my_app/rel/my_app/releases/0.0.1/my_app -boot_var ERTS_LIB_DIR /Users/me/code/my_app/rel/my_app/erts-6.3.1/../lib -config /Users/me/code/my_app/rel/my_app/releases/0.0.1/sys.config -pa /Users/me/code/my_app/rel/my_app/lib/consolidated -name my_app@127.0.0.1 -setcookie my_app -user Elixir.IEx.CLI -extra --no-halt +iex -- console

17562   0.0  0.0  2452008    588   ??  S     4:03pm   0:00.00 /Users/me/code/my_app/rel/my_app/erts-6.3.1/bin/run_erl -daemon /Users/me/code/my_app/rel/my_app/tmp/erl_pipes/my_app/ /Users/me/code/my_app/rel/my_app/log exec "/Users/me/code/my_app/rel/my_app/bin/my_app" "console"

$ tail /var/log/system.log

Jun  9 16:03:14 me.local my_app[17565][17597]: Starting up
```

I can tell that my application is not running because it should consume from a queue and write to a data store. However when starting the release, the queue is never consumed. Unfortunately I can't find any more log output or errors aside from the one "Starting up" line.

Is there an argument I need to pass to exrm's start command to get it to run my app?

If not, is there perhaps a way to debug this via pointing the logs somewhere or inspecting internal processes?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your previously posted `mix.exs`, you need to add your own application to `applications`. This tells the VM which applications should be started at runtime. Some applications are started out of the box (such as `:kernel`, `:stdlib`, etc.), and you don't need to add those, but anything you wanted started automatically should go in `applications`. You can put apps which do not need to be started in `included_applications`, as those are loaded, but not started.

Comment: putting `:my_app` in the `applications` list leads to an infinite loop in both `iex -S mix` and `mix release`. I'm guessing perhaps I should create a separate app within `my_app` that performs the actual work, and then add it to the `applications` list? Eg. `:my_app_worker`

Comment: I was mistaken about putting `:my_app` in `applications` actually, that isn't required. Do you have a link to the source for this project that you can share? Something isn't quite right, but it's hard to troubleshoot from just the `mix.exs`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your app in mix.exs in order to start it automatically:

```
def application do
  [applications: [],
   mod: {MyAppModule, []}]
end
```

So *mod: {MyAppModule, []}* means that MyAppModule.start_link() will be called automatically.